# wp_mail - not working when $headers are set

Tags: php, wordpress, email

In my files the wp_mail function does not send a mail if I set the optional $headers parameter. I just don't receive any mail when it's set. If I leave it away, however, the mail arrives.

```
$headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
wp_mail($to, $subjects, $message, $headers); // not working
wp_mail($to, $subjects, $message ); // working
```

What could cause this?

Comment: Are you using that exact `From:` email to test?

Comment: Actually I was. From your questions I guess that was wrong? When putting only the emailadress actually the mail now arrives but still the chosen sender mail address is not shown, only the standard wp email.

Comment: If PHP saw no errors and you're only diagnostic is "the email was not received" then its unlikely to be issue with PHP or whatever you are running on top of that. There are a lot of components in between PHP and your mailbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your answer to my question:

> Are you using that exact From: email to test? –  Anonymous
>   Actually I was ... – ink

It seems that your `From:` address doesn't match the domain you're sending the email from. The mail server you're sending the email to likely rejected the email when it saw that you were trying to spoof the sender address.

Comment: Aha okay I see. I guess I tried to use it for the wrong purpose.
What I actually wanted to is to create a form where a user types in his mail adress and a message which gets sent to me. And in my inbox I wanted the email address to be shown as the one of the sender so I can simply click "answer" and him write back.
Is way to achieve this?

Comment: No, I would hope not. That would be a dramatic security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `$header` from `wp_mail()` and add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');

function new_mail_from($old) {
    return 'admin@yourdomain.com';
}
function new_mail_from_name($old) {
    return 'Your Blog Name';
}
```

source:
 https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from
and https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from_name

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but somehow this makes it fail as well. When put into my functions file the mail does not arrive.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to match the from address domain to from-email and reply-to email addresses.

Here is a complete example with headers, attachments.

```
$from_name = 'name';
$from = 'from@your-domain.com';
$subject = 'test';    
$body = 'Test';
$to = 'test@example.test';
$bcc = 'bccemail@example.text';
$attachments[] = WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/'.$path_to_file;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$headers[] = 'From: '.$from_name.' <'.$from.'>';
$headers[] = 'Reply-To: '.$from_name.' <'.$from.'>';
//add BCC if want 
$headers[] = 'Bcc: '.$bcc;

$success = wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
```