# Send additional email in WooCommerce in a processing status order (functions.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, phpmailer

I need to send these two emails after the checkout.

1.- Woocommerce automatic email (summerizing the order, prince, total price, etc).

2.- Email with aditional information.

I have been looking and I can't do it from WooCommerce plugin and I can't use other plugins like Shopmagic, so ... It has to be with code.

After than a lot of time searching, I think could be something like this.

(The order of status control is `processing` and no `completed` because I'm testing with test-mode in Stripe and Stripe, in test mode, orders are defined as "processing" status, not `completed`.

What I have from now in my `functions.php` file is this:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

function order_processing( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $to_email = $order["billing_address"];
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <alexiglesiasvortex@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail($to_email, 'subject', '<h1>This is a test for my new pending email.</h1><p>Agree, this is a test</p>', $headers );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_processing', 'order_processing' );
```

Currently, this is not working ... I don't get any error and checkout ends correctly, but no new email arrives to my inbox.

I need some help, guys, someone can help me? Thank you a lot and have a good monday!

Comment: I recommend you debug by writing into a log file. Also, can you access the email server's log files? (My guess is, the email is being rejected by the mail server.)

Comment: Omit the $headers in wp_mail() and try again. Does it work now? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322039/wp-mail-not-working-when-headers-are-set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any `woocommerce_payment_processing` hooks in the WooCommerce documentation. Try [**`woocommerce_order_status_changed`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.373) instead.

Also you are accessing the billing email incorrectly. `$order` is an object and you cannot get the billing email as if it were an array. You can use the `get_billing_email` method of the **WC_Order** class.

```
// send a custom email when the order status changes to "processing"
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'send_custom_email_order_processing', 10, 4 );
function send_custom_email_order_processing( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ) {

    // only if the new order status is "processing"
    if ( $to_status == 'processing' ) {
        $to_email = $order->get_billing_email();
        $headers = 'From: Your Name <alexiglesiasvortex@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
        wp_mail( $to_email, 'subject', '<h1>This is a test for my new pending email.</h1><p>Agree, this is a test</p>', $headers );
    }

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*